# How to do beautiful date format?

Tags: html, mysql

I am trying to show many dates on front end but its not beauty ,I am using code `<li>` format.Date format is correct now,like `19 May 2016` I don't want to change format like `19 5 2016`. Which method is the best to arrange pretty well ? [image: photo]

```
<?              
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM  ShowFillter GROUP BY Image_Date order by Image_Date desc";
                            $objQuery = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die ("Error Query [".$sql."]");
                            while($objResult1 = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery))
                            {
                        ?>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="<?=$objResult1['Image_Date'];?>">
                            <a href="#">
                                <?=date('d M Y', strtotime($objResult1['Image_Date']));?>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <? 
                            }    
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ul>` before li

```
echo "<ul>";              
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM  ShowFillter GROUP BY Image_Date order by Image_Date desc";
                            $objQuery = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die ("Error Query [".$sql."]");
                            while($objResult1 = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery))
                            {
                        ?>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="<?=$objResult1['Image_Date'];?>">
                            <a href="#">
                                <?=date('d M Y', strtotime($objResult1['Image_Date']));?>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <? 
                            }    
                        ?>
echo "</ul>";
```